# How to solve this TypeError: string indices must be integers?

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

I'm new to python and may not be very familiar with the detailed syntax rules.

Can i know how this error can be solved? It points to line 6,7,8 and i'm not sure what went wrong. Thanks!

```
def calculate_average_expenditure(a):
    totalincome = 0
    totalsavings = 0
    count = 0
    for item in a:
        if (item['AGE2011'] >= 20 and item['AGE2011'] <= 30):
            totalincome += item['INC2011']
            totalsavings += item['SAV2011']
            count += 1

    totalexpenditure = totalincome-totalsavings
    return totalexpenditure/count
```

EDIT:
Thanks, i got it working by tweaking how the method is called.

```
a={ 'uen': 's1234567h', 'AGE2011':21, 'INC2011':100, 'SAV2011':80}
b={ 'uen': 's1234567h', 'AGE2011':28, 'INC2011':300, 'SAV2011':100}
x=[a,b]
calculate_average_expenditure(x)
```

Comment: What tpe is `a`? What type is `item` (`str`, I guess)? What do you want to do?

Comment: It looks like your function is expecting a sequence of mappings (such as a list of dicts) but you are passing in something else.

Comment: thanks a lot! i got it working this way.

>>> a={ 'uen': 's1234567h', 'AGE2011':21, 'INC2011':100, 'SAV2011':80}
>>> b={ 'uen': 's1234567h', 'AGE2011':28, 'INC2011':300, 'SAV2011':100}
>>> x=[a,b]
>>> calculate_average_expenditure(x)
  110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the parameter `a` is bound to a list of strings. Can you show how you call `calculate_average_expenditure(...)` and and what `...` contains?

Comment: I have these:

>>> d={ 'uen': 's1234567h', 'AGE2011':21, 'INC2011':100, 'SAV2011':80}
>>> calculate_average_expenditure(d)
  21

I'm converting from java, and trying to create something like an ArrayList. Thanks!

Comment: Try: `calculate_average_expenditure([d])`.

Comment: thanks a lot! i got it working this way.

>>> a={ 'uen': 's1234567h', 'AGE2011':21, 'INC2011':100, 'SAV2011':80}
>>> b={ 'uen': 's1234567h', 'AGE2011':28, 'INC2011':300, 'SAV2011':100}
>>> x=[a,b]
>>> calculate_average_expenditure(x)
  110